# Inserting tags (WYSIWYG JavaScript editor)

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

I'm currently working on a WYSIWYG editor for a client (It's not like any other editor, it will also be able to insert drawings using HTML5) And I've been looking at and using several ways to insert content.

Ok, so I have a div with contentEditable set to "true", and I'm stuck on a way make the text a different size/font by inserting tags before and after to cursor, or something similar. I've tried using Design Mode with execcommand, but that didn't work. Can somebody help?

Comment: Have you looked at other WYSIWYG editors to see how they do things?

Comment: Have you considered building on an existing WYSIWYG editor? The need for the ability to insert drawings may not exclude that possibility.

Comment: I believe there is TinyMCE integration with PaintWeb (html 5 canvas editor). http://www.robodesign.ro/paintweb/trunk/demos/demo-tinymce.html

Answer (score 2):

You have some reading to do. If you're taking this on, be aware that it's a tricky and time-consuming task to write a WYSIWYG editor in JavaScript: there are many bugs, quirks and discrepancies between browsers and the fact that you're here asking such a general question on Stack Overflow at this stage doesn't bode well. Most of the browser makers have easily-found documentation on their implementations of `designMode` and `contenteditable` (see [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/midas), for example), so you could start there. To do things like inserting an element at the cursor, you'll also need to learn how to deal with [Selections](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/selection), [DOM Level 2 Ranges](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ranges.html) and [TextRanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533042%28VS.85%29.aspx) in IE up to version 8. Finally, looking at the source code of some the popular editors such as TinyMCE and CKEditor may help; simpler, smaller editors (there's loads around) might be even more helpful.