# Textarea Selection Index

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have a textarea control in my website.
I want to retrieve start and end position of selected text in the text area, for Internet Explorer.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might I encourage you to use [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/)?

> A cross-browser JavaScript range and selection library. It provides a simple standards-based API for performing common DOM Range and Selection tasks in all major browsers, abstracting away the wildly different implementations of this functionality between Internet Explorer and DOM-compliant browsers.

See [Selection Objects in Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/RangySelection).

Answer (score 1):

`txtarea.selectionStart`

and

`txtarea.selectionEnd`

are the indices of the selection.

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543476/javascript-selectionstart-selectionend) shows you how to use them.

To read more on selected text, see this [Introduction to Range](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html). Specifically, you will have to use [Microsoft Text Range](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872.aspx) for Internet Explorer.