# Add a text to a textarea and mark it using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

After clicking a button a text should be added to a `textarea`. But if I am using `+=` it adds the text at the end of the value of the `textarea`. I would like that after clicking the button the text is added to the part where I am writing at the moment. I hope you understand the question :)

And there's another question: After the text is added to the `textarea` it should select a part of the added text. Like this:
[b]boldText[/b] - This is the added text. Now the script should select 'boldText'.

**I do not use jQuery on this site!**

Well, here is my script so far (not the whole script):

```
(...) <script>
function insertBold () {
    document.form2.content.value += "[b]boldText[/b]";
}
</script> (...)
<div class="formatBtn" onClick="insertBold()"><b>B</b></div>
<form name="form2>
<textarea style="width:100%; height:300px; font:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;" type="text" placeholder="Inhalt" name="content"></textarea><br><br>
</form> (...)
```

Comment: can  you clarify what you mean by `mark`

Comment: @cmorrissey oops sorry. Select the text. I'll corect it right now :)

Comment: Purpose of jQuery tag?

Comment: @A. Wolff On this site I am using no jQuery.

Comment: `setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd, [optional] selectionDirection);` is what you are looking for

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974807/textarea-selection-index

Comment: @cmorrissey Where do I have to put it and what do I have to set for selection-Start and -End?

Comment: I've added a pure JS answer below. Not sure why so many people don't use jquery, as it greatly simplifies and enhances actions like these. Adding jquery is as simple as adding a jquery cdn link to your header like `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`. Perhaps there are performance reasons?

Comment: @Brino I use jQuery on all sites but this one. These are the webmaster/admin tools for a site and after I used jQuery the admin tools weren't working anymore. But I like jQuery and I use it on almost every site.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following. It will add the text to the cursor position

your html :

```
  <textarea id="txt" rows="10" cols="30">There is some text here.</textarea>
```

your jquery

```
<textarea id="txt" rows="15" cols="70">There is some text here.</textarea>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="OK" />
```

here is the link for jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cb97z2fk/

Comment: Is there also a way to do it without jQuery?

Comment: Why do you need to do it without jQuery? jQuery is developed to make these actions easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use textareas as rich text editors. You can't make some text bold and other text not. It's all or nothing.

You can however add text and select it. I added two buttons, one to add text and select it, and one to add '[b]text[/b]' and select 'text'.

**PURE JS - JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/x3wkkqh4/3/
**JQUERY  - JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/x3wkkqh4/

**PURE JS**

```
(function () {
    var btn = document.getElementById('formatBtn');
    btn.onclick=function(){insertAndSelect();};
    var btn2 = document.getElementById('formatBtnBolded');
    btn2.onclick=function(){insertAndSelectBolded();};
})();

function insertAndSelect() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('content');    
    var texttoinsertvalue = document.getElementById('textToInsert').value;
     var selectionStart = textarea.value.length;   
    textarea.value = textarea.value + texttoinsertvalue;
    var selectionEnd = textarea.value.length;
    selectRange(textarea,selectionStart, selectionEnd);
}

function insertAndSelectBolded() {
    var textarea = document.getElementById('content');    
    var texttoinsertvalue = document.getElementById('textToInsert').value;
     var selectionStart = textarea.value.length+3;   
    textarea.value = textarea.value + '[b]'+texttoinsertvalue+'[/b]';
    var selectionEnd = textarea.value.length - 4;
    selectRange(textarea,selectionStart, selectionEnd);
}

function selectRange(e, start, end){       
    if (!e) return;
    else if (e.setSelectionRange) { e.focus(); e.setSelectionRange(start, end); } /* WebKit */ 
    else if (e.createTextRange) { var range = e.createTextRange(); range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', end); range.moveStart('character', start); range.select(); } /* IE */
    else if (e.selectionStart) { e.selectionStart = start; e.selectionEnd = end; }
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('#formatBtn').click(function () {
        insertAndSelect();
    })    
    $('#formatBtnBolded').click(function () {
        insertAndSelectBolded();
    })
});

function insertAndSelect() {
    var textarea = $('#content');
    var selectionStart = textarea.val().length;
    textarea.val(textarea.val() + $('#textToInsert').val());
    var selectionEnd = textarea.val().length;
    textarea.selectRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
}

function insertAndSelectBolded() {
    var textarea = $('#content');
    var selectionStart = textarea.val().length+3;
    textarea.val(textarea.val() + '[b]'+$('#textToInsert').val()+'[/b]');
    var selectionEnd = textarea.val().length-4;
    textarea.selectRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
}

//use this function to set the range.
$.fn.selectRange = function(start, end) {
    var e = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));
    if (!e) return;
    else if (e.setSelectionRange) { e.focus(); e.setSelectionRange(start, end); } /* WebKit */ 
    else if (e.createTextRange) { var range = e.createTextRange(); range.collapse(true); range.moveEnd('character', end); range.moveStart('character', start); range.select(); } /* IE */
    else if (e.selectionStart) { e.selectionStart = start; e.selectionEnd = end; }
};
```

Comment: NOTE: I got the function to select a range from a SO answer, but now I can't find it. If you find it, comment or edit with the link please.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this could work.

```
let textarea = document.getElementById("yourID");
let startPos = textarea.selectionStart;
let endPos = textarea.selectionEnd;

if (startPos == end){
  // when textarea is not marked,
  // or when a specific piece of text is not marked
 textarea.value = textarea.value.slice(0, start)
    + "Your text to be inserted"
    + textarea.value.slice(start, textarea.value.length);
} else {
  // Specific piece of text marked
  // specific example for when making a piece of the text italic

  let opening = "<i>"
  let ending = "</i>"

  let startOfString = textarea.value.slice(0, start);
  let added = opening + textarea.value.slice(start, end) + ending;
  let endOfString = textarea.value.slice(end, textarea.value.length);
    
  textarea.value = startOfString + added + endOfString;
}
```

Case 1:

Before

```
Some random text *cursor placed here* follwed by some more random text
```

After:

```
Some random text "Your inserted text" followed by some more random text
```

Case 2:

Before (text between * is marked text)

```
Hello world, *it's a beautiful* day
```

After

```
Hello world, <i>it's a beautiful</i> day
```